# Click on button/submit when it appears on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where a button or a submit form will appear at an unknown time. I don´t know the id, class or xpath of the button/form but i know what the text of the button will be. It will say: "`Click here`". The page will only have that button and some text.

How can i create a script that as fast as possible will click the button when it appears?

This is only an example and i know that `getElementByText/getElementByValue` doesn´t exists:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint</div>

        <button>Click me<button>          

        <form> 
            <input type="submit" value="Click me">
        </form>

        <div> occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita</div>
    </body>

</html>

<script>
    intervalFunction(){
        setInterval(clickFunction, 500);
    }

    clickFunction(){
        if(docment.getElementByText("Click me")){
            document.getElementBy("Click me").click();
        }

        else if{docment.getElementByText("Click me")){
            document.getElementvalue("Click me").click();}

        }
        else 
           intervalFunction();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Surely you must be able to work out the DOM path to the element?

Comment: the code you have shown is not valid JS - and `document.querySelector("[value='Click me']")` will give you the button in plain JS, `$("[value='Click me']"))` in jQuery

Comment: if the page is yours you can always add a `change` event on the document and on each change go over all buttons `$( ":button" )` and see if the text matches `Click here`. but if you do not own the page, then this sounds like cheating/hacking, which you should not be doing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just curious as to why you would like this kind of behavior. For answer, I am not a total expert but you can use `getElementByTagName()` if at least you know it's a button. post that you may also be able to filter if it's a submit button and if it's display is hidden or not

Comment: this is not my page. I know that some time on a specific date a button will appear that i want to click as fast as possible. I only know that the button text = Click me. How can i create a script that will click the button or input without knowing the id, xpath or class?

Comment: If it is not your page, you need to run some kind of user script or inject a script on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Click me']").length > 0) {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Click me']")[0].click();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This works when the button is already there, but how can i use it when the button does not exists?

Comment: It works even if button is not there, as we are using setInterval, it will check for every 100ms for button, if button exists then it triggers click event.

Comment: replace "intervalFunction(){ setInterval(clickFunction, 500); }" with the above code

Comment: Yes, but it is not my webpage. it´s a public page. If i have the webpage open in my chrome browser. Where to it put the script?

Comment: then you can add a script tag in html page in chrome developer tool, by using Edit As HTML

Comment: when i insert it in the console log it only runs once

Comment: You mean, you want to run this script whenever the page is loaded. If so, then you will have to create a extension in that particular browser (may be not a good idea). You can add this script to the webpage source but it is not your page it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You marked this jQuery - it could be as simple as

```js
// The code you need
var tId;
$(function() {
    tId=setInterval(function() {
      var $but=$("[value='Click me']");
      if ($but.length>0) {
        console.log("found");
        clearInterval(tId);
        $but.click();
      }  
    },100)
});


//------------------------------------------------
// other code that inserts and shows it's clicked
$(function() {
  $("#container").on("click","[value='Click me']",function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#form1").append('<input type="button" value="Click me">');
    },3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="div1">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint</div>


        <form id="form1"> 

        </form>

        <div> occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select button with attr/value selector

```
$('input[type="button"][value="Click  here"]').on('click',function(){
//code
});
```

Comment: You need to delegate and use setInterval

Comment: Why on attach the event to the dynamic content as I think ?

Answer (score 0):

As the form/button will appear at an unknown time, You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and listen DOM changes.

Here in snippet I have used `setTimeout` to simulate button added dynamically.

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var element = document.querySelector('#target');
setTimeout(function() {
  $(element).append('<button>Click here</button>');
}, 3000)

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "childList") {
      console.log('Button found do the needful');
      //$(":button:contains('Click here')").get(0).click();
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  childList: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: It seems the "Button found" is shown from the beginning

Comment: @mplungjan, It was due to listening element for `document.body`

Comment: I think mine is more simple and compatible

Comment: @mplungjan, Mine is faster. anyway I think OP seems to creating hack for flash sale

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will help:

```js
$('input[value="ClickMe"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="ClickMe" onclick="alert('clicked');" />
```