# Run jquery code in angularJS app document ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am  trying to run some jquery code in angular app, the code that i am trying to run involves to hook on some selectors/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  Configuration.anchorToUseForMainSearch = $("#header_element")
}
```

This selector return "length: 0" as the DOM is not loaded yet,
There is some other event that i should use?

Tried to use this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        // Your document is ready, place your code here
});
```

But it was the same result..

Comment: will the element `#header_element` will load through `angular route/partial loading`?

Comment: @Koushik Chatterjee . no. The jquery code will run from external project that hooks into the angular app

Comment: To clarify, you mean the document selector?

Comment: add MutationObserver to body, once you found the element, remove the observer

Comment: @JeffHoward- yes

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee- i will google for it now, i dont know what is "MutationObserver "

Comment: see this [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for your reference. Still if you want, I can post a detail answer.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee - The jquery code will run from external project (not an angular app) that hooks into the angular app, i am trying to get the DOM loading in order to manipulate DOM elments

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee - can you please post a detailed answer?

Comment: yeah, Sure, will post soon...

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792482) might help

Comment: @E.Meir added an answer, please check :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a directive for this and set the timeout for executing your code.

Comment: The jquery code will run from external project that hooks into the angular app, so i cant make a directive for it as its external app.
The regular document.ready suppose to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are headed down the wrong path here I would say. The Angular way would avoid using jQuery. If you absolutely must, I would suggest you put it in a .run() attached to your main module. I would expect the document to be "ready" at the point that this function would fire.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .run(function myAppRunFn() {
     // commit sins here. 
  });
```

Documented here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: The jquery code will run from external project (not an angular app) that hooks into the angular app. so i have no way for using this answer..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var target = $("#wrapperDiv")[0]; //or document.body when you not sure
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if($(mutation.addedNodes).filter('#header_element').length) {
        //code for what you want here
        console.log("Item added to DOM");
    }  
  });   
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Adding Element from some other code');
    $("#innerDiv").append("<div id='header_element'>");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapperDiv">

    <div id="innerDiv">
    
    </div>

<div>
```